# Sugerencias para bautizar la sala de chat

Tags: discusión, chat

Surgió la idea de bautizar la [sala de chat general](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872) con un nombre propio, algo diferente a "StackOverflow en Español" lo cual -en principio- ya queda claro.

Por cierto esto es algo que ya se hizo en otros sitios de la red.

Este espacio es para escuchar propuestas...

Las reglas básicas del Post son:

- Un solo nombre por respuesta
- Votar el nombre que mas te guste (la respuesta con el nombre)
- Votar en esta [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/772/2027) si quieres que siga el nombre "StackOverflow en Español".
- Los votos en contra no cuentan, solo los votos a favor.

Definiremos el ganador:

- El nombre mas votado hasta el 15 de septiembre (la fecha es discutible)

A pensar nombres!!!

Comment: Faltaría dejar muy claro _cómo_ y __cuándo__ se elegirá el nombre ganador.

Comment: buen punto. editado.

Comment: Leí la pregunta... sigo leyendo y veo 2 respuestas con votos negativos... Sería bueno que aclares si se cuentan o no los negativos (según entendí, no se cuentan).

Comment: Votar en contra la pregunta si quieres que siga el nombre "StackOverflow en Español". //Nótese: "la pregunta", no hace referencia a las propuestas que se dan como respuestas

Comment: Creo que deberia haber una opcion en las respuestas **mantener el nombre** para que sea mas clara la votación

Comment: de acuerdo @jasilva vamos a publicarla

Comment: A Todos, no puedo hacerlo ahora. Si alguien quiere/puede editar y hacer las aclaraciones... Osea editar las reglas. Sino lo haré luego ;) gracias por el feedback.

Comment: @JuanM podríamos hacerlo featured? :D

Comment: @rnd Viendo que mantener el nombre parece que va a ganar, propongo: no poner fecha límite, dejarlo abierto para siempre... Si en algún momento otra propuesta la supera, en ese momento se cambia el nombre.

Comment: @Mariano Eso suena muy interesante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Stack Overflow en español

(mantener el nombre)

Comment: puff... y esos que dicen que es aburrido rebautizar con el mismo nombre... no han visto este post.

Answer (score 3):

## Desbordamiento de pila

Answer (score 1):

## La Hermandad del Código 2.0!

Answer (score 1):

Sugerencia #8795

## Aquí se habla español

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bL_74rbzQZo :D

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugerencia:

## Ñ Driven Development

Answer (score 1):

**No te olvides de poner el WHERE en el DELETE FROM**

Comment: [Importante](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_cVJgIz_Cs)

Answer (score 0):

Sugerencia:

## Todos somos root

Answer (score 0):

## Café SOes

Answer (score 0):

Sugerencia #5412:

## Programamos y hablamos en español

Answer (score -1):

Mi sugerencia:

## La banda y la parranda / Banda y parranda.

Answer (score -1):

## La Taberna de los Brothers 2.0!

Answer (score -1):

Mi sugerencia:

## Hackers del mundo

Answer (score -1):

**Programación Hispano-parlante**

Answer (score -2):

Otra sugerencia:

## Programación para dummies